# infinite scroll down using selenium alwais fail because of automatic reload of the page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scroll down this page https://www.newsnow.com/us/World?type=ln&d=1609455600 by clicking on the button `"view more headlines"` so I can scrape headlines of previous days.
But the page on the driver reloads automatically after some loops (some clicks on view more headlines) and returns to the initial position.
This is the code :

```
url = 'https://www.newsnow.com/us/World?type=ln&d=1609455600'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options)

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
# driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
for i in range(3000):
    try:
        elem =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'btn--primary__label')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
        elem.click()
        print(f'click {i} done')
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        print('end of the scrolling down')
        break
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
# ...
# working with the sope
```

Answer (score 0):

Click the underlaying element you got another overlaying element by accident.
A better way would be to use requests though.

```
driver.get('https://www.newsnow.com/us/World?type=ln&d=1609455600')
for i in range(3000):
    try:
        elem =WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='view more headlines']/parent::a")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
        print(f'click {i} done')
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception as e:
        #print(e)
        print('end of the scrolling down')
        break
```